# rendering true type fonts for non-latin scripts

Tags: truetype, glyph

I am working on this project for LED displays which have to support multiple Indian languages to support the poorest of people in India ti display their entitlements to free food rations and kerosene on LED display panels using GPRS modems. Bandwidth is limited. cant use the bitmap strong as data is heavy. NEEd to transmit in ASCII and build the font in LED display which is 8-but processor based.

How can i extract the glyph infomraiton in a font and use it to generate an index of fixed pixel count? The output would look like decoder.ttf font on an LED screen. How to extract the rule base or whatever it is within the font that guides how characters inter-mingle (by superscripting/ subscripting) over the neighbouring characters?

Answer (score 1):

> How can i extract the glyph infomraiton in a font and use it to generate an index of fixed pixel count?

Ensure that the font you're using is "fixed pitch", also known as "monospaced" as opposed to proportionally-spaced (each character takes up a different amount of space, horizontally). If the font is not fixed-pitch, you will not get correct results trying to force it into a fixed pixel count.

> How to extract the rule base or whatever it is within the font that guides how characters inter-mingle (by superscripting/ subscripting) over the neighbouring characters?

Assuming that you are using a font that contains OpenType layout information (GSUB, GPOS, and so on), you will need to read that information and apply it. There are a number of [libraries](http://www.google.com/search?&q=pango+icu+harfbuzz) to do this if your platform doesn't provide something already. Or you can roll your own, using the [OpenType specification](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/TTOCHAP1.htm) as a guide (good luck...it is not a trivial undertaking).